# CakePHP 2 Auth Not Working - Blowfish

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, blowfish

I'm using CakePHP 2.8.5. It's not letting me log in "Username or password is incorrect". This seems totally straightforward in the docs but it isn't working for me. I wonder if my model/data structure might be confusing CakePHP. I have a Users model, but the logins are associated with an Admins model. The login form and action are in the Pages model (it has forms for multiple models).

in AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Flash',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Admin',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        ),
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'authError' => 'Please log in',
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

My login view, in /View/Pages. "email" is the username field:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Admin'); 
echo $this->Form->input('email'); 
echo $this->Form->input('password'); 
echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); 
?>
```

PagesController:

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }
    }}
```

Top of Admin model:

```
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```

Automatic Blowfish encryption in Admin model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data['Admin']['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data['Admin']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data['Admin']['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

I notice if I enter the same password for different Admins, I get a different encryption result, but I've read that's normal.

If you want to see anything else, I'll add it.

Comment: "I notice if I enter the same password for different Admins, I get a different encryption result, but I've read that's normal."  That's not normal.  The same password should generate the same hash.  That's kind of the whole point of the hash/compare.  If they weren't the same, you couldn't compare.

Comment: That's what it seemed like to me, but then I read this Q-A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667478/blowfish-in-cakephp-is-generating-different-passwords-everytime

Comment: I'm not sure what they're talking about, but it seems bassakwards to me.  How could you possibly compare a password if its hash changes every time.  I use cake every day all day, and have never had this issue.  There must be something going on.  I also know that it's the same, because when I manually generate a user, I sometimes copy/paste an existing hash into the new person's password field, and the previous password works fine.  (yes, not pretty, but w/e) :)

Comment: `The same password should generate the same hash` @Dave this is completely false when applied to blowfish. Here's [some random online tool](http://www.passwordtool.hu/blowfish-password-hash-generator) to demonstrate. Also a useful reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#refsect1-function.crypt-examples - note that the hash of a password contains the salt to verify that the hash is correct.

Comment: @AD7six - I certainly bow to your expertise on this one (not sarcastic).  I thought my logic was sound, but apparently there's a gap in it.  How can I copy/paste a hashed password field from one user to the next and have the same password function correctly for both?  Or for that matter, how does it compare my password when typed in against the one in the database if it hashes differently every time?

Comment: `How can I copy/paste a hashed password field from one user to the next and have the same password function correctly for both?` the hash contains the salt to the hash function - you're copying the hashed password _and_ the same salt doing that. `how does it compare my password when typed in against the one in the database if it hashes differently every time?` the hash is different if no salt (previous hash) is provided because it generates a new salt `$hashed_password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The userModel key is in the wrong place

Compare the config in the question:

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Flash',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Admin',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        ),
```

To the config [in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers):

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Member')
);
```

In the question `userModel` is a top-level key, in the docs it is part of the individual authenticate keys. Looking at the [api examples](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-AuthComponent.html#$authenticate) (or the doc blocks in the source code) the error is more clear:

> ... you can define settings that should be set to all authentications objects using the 'all' key:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'all' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Users.User',
        'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
    ),
    'Form',
    'Basic'
);
```

It *is* possible to define a global `userModel` for all authenticate objects to use, but the syntax is simply different than the question.

### Use the all key

Therefore to define a user model to use for all authenticate options, use the all key:

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Flash',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        //'userModel' => 'Admin', // <- no
        'authenticate' => array(
            'all' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Admin' // <- yes
            ),
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        ),
```