# Make a token in Node.js like CakePHP?

Tags: node.js, cakephp

CakePHP makes unique passwords from Hash encryption. I want to do the same thing in Node.js?

In CakePHP if you make a password with Hash it makes a different Hash with the same password a second time. I want to do the same thing in Node. How do I do this? For eg) CakePHP Hash password 'helloworld' produces 'kdjfkj32434' password. CakePHP hash password again 'helloworld' produces 'adfsdfdfkj' different password.
I want to do the same thing in Node, is it possible?

Comment: You should read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Yes it's possible you could probably use a password hashing library for this instead of doing it yourself. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs

Comment: Yeah, please don't try to roll your own crypto.  Thar be dragons.

Answer (score 2):

Cake is using blowfish to generate hashes. It generates a different hash every time because it's able to store a randomly generated salt as part of the hash. I've written an explanation of how it works over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699357/2719538

Don't roll your own crypto. Leave it to an established library to do bcrypt hashing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a uuid.

*a UUID is either guaranteed to be different or is, at least, extremely likely to be different from any other UUID generated until 3400 A.D.*

Here's a package that'll let you do just that.  [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

If, however, all you want to do is take a user-supplied string and hash it, there's a package for that as well [password-hash-and-salt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash-and-salt)

Comment: What you do with it after the fact is entirely up to you.  I read this as requiring a _unique token._  Could use it to salt a generator.  If it doesn't _have_ to be unique then there are plenty of other ways generate a seemingly-random string.

Comment: Fair enough the question is broad enough to consider your answer correct...