# How to work out how password is encrypted in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

We host a CakePHP site for someone. They would like to change the password for their account and unfortunately the original developers didn't build this functionality into the site so I was going to update the password in PHPMyAdmin.

I have tried entering the password and then hashing it using the MD5 dropdown in the database. I've also tried SHA1 but when I try logging in on the frontend, it fails.

How can I tell what type of hash method is used on the system?

Comment: https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Auth.DefaultPasswordHasher.html

Comment: what cake version?

Comment: I don't know. How would I find this out?

Comment: find a `VERSION.txt` file in your application. if is cake 2 you should see it under `lib/Cake` directory, if is cake 3 it is located in the `vendor/cakephp/cakephp` directory. Show us what it says

Comment: Hi arilia. Thank you for your help. It's version 1.3.12

Comment: I've been digging through the code and found this in the core.php file, not sure if it helps:

/**
 * A random string used in security hashing methods.
 */
 Configure::write('Security.salt', 'Hdhskhh482hdhjnBNeuwuOEU28DhdKZMEI');

/**
 * A random numeric string (digits only) used to encrypt/decrypt strings.
 */
 Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '5464604981684068131060819608049');

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp uses PHP's built in `password_hash` method in it's DefaultPasswordHasher.

You can override this by implementing the \Cake\Auth\AbtrasctPasswordHasher and configuring the Auth component with your implementation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php#L49
Implementing Custom Hasher
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes

Answer (score -1):

Cake is using blowfish to generate password hashes. It generates a different hash every time because it's able to store a randomly generated salt as part of the hash. I've written an explanation of how it works over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699357/2719538

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how would I change the password in the database? I'm using PHPMyAdmin.